# Help identifying set from 3 sealed bags with Star Wars figs

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

I got these three bags in a lot. Looks like there are two snow troopers and bag 4 has a bunch of fluorescent green circle pieces. Any help would be appreciated for this first time poster.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Bricks.SE! Based on the 10 x 3 Wedges and your description, these bags likely belong to [75100 First Order Snowspeeder](https://brickset.com/sets/75100-1/First-Order-Snowspeeder):

[image: 75100 First Order Snowspeeder]

The instructions for this set are available here:

https://www.lego.com/biassets/bi/6136428.pdf